# Set the highest four bits of a int64 value in c++

Tags: c++, bit

I've a c++ problem. I need to modify the four highest bits of a int64 value.
The highest bit must be "1" and the next three bits must be "0". The rest of the value should not be changed.

Can you help me please. Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Can you do it with a smaller number, e.g. 16 bits?

Comment: What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: Look at [bitwise AND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/bitwise-and-operator-amp?view=vs-2019)

Comment: do and binary operation & with the number

Comment: Look at [bitwise OR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/bitwise-inclusive-or-operator-pipe?view=vs-2019)

Comment: `y = (~(0xfull << 59) & x) | (8ull<<59)`

Answer (score 3):

To set bits to 0, you can use bitwise AND with a bitmask:

```
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
AND 0000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
--------------------------------------------------------------------
    0000bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

To set bits to 1, you can use bitwise OR with a bitmask:

```
   0000bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
OR 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
-------------------------------------------------------------------
   1000bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

Note that `int64` is a signed integer, and result of modifying the most significant bit with bitwise and / or has implementation defined result (in practice, this means that the value depends on how negative numbers are represented on the system). Bitwise operations are typically performed on unsigned integers only.

Generating the bitmasks themselves is quite tricky if you need them to be signed. This is because left shifting a positive number into non-representable range has undefined behaviour. It is best to create an unsigned mask, and reinterpret it.

---

With the assumption that you actually want to use unsigned instead:

```
uint64_t input = whatever;
input &= 0x0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFu;
input |= 0x8000000000000000u;
```

The bitmasks can also be generated using shifts, which is useful way to generalise the operation for integers of different sizes:

```
using U = some_unsigned_integer;
U last_byte_offset = (sizeof(U) - 1) * 8;
U and_mask = ~(U(0xF0) << last_byte_offset);
U or_mask  =   U(0x80) << last_byte_offset;
```

Comment: That's it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First create mask for 3 bits:

```
0b0111 << 60
```

Then use this mask to clear that bits:

```
x &= ~((uint64_t)0b0111 << 60)
```

And finally set the last bit:

```
x |= ((uint64_t)1 << 63)
```

---

Actually, its kinda strange you need to edit bits in signed 8bytes, not unsigned.
Maybe, you have some deeper problem in your design.

---

Fixed that int flaw.

Comment: Seems OK now. Minor nitpick 7 seems too much of a magic number. I recommend `0b0111` instead, which is obvious from the bit-pattern perspective.

Answer (score -1):

First, we need a mask which is 1 everywhere except in the 4 highest bits:

```
int64 mask = ~ (int64(0xf) << 60);
```

What did we do?  `0xf` is a binary 00...001111 . We moved the binary digits 59 positions to the left, so it becomes 111100...00, then we negated the whole thing so that it would be 000011...11 .

Note the casting to int64. Without it, 0xf might be 32-bit integer, and `0xf<<60` is also 32-bit (and it's value may be anything).

Now clear the highest 4 bits:

```
x = x & mask;
```

But we need the highest bit to be 1. For this, do bitwise or with binary 100...00 :

```
x = x | (int64(1) << 63);
```

We are done.

Answer (score -1):

`x = (x | 0x80000000) & 0x8fffffff ;`

The first part, `(x | 0x80000000)`, sets the highest bit to one.
The second part, `& 0x8fffffff`, sets three next highest bits to zero.